# how to remove space under a table?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

Here what I've done and whats my problem. First of all i got a big table with a lot of td the first td on top of my table containt anoter table and (here come my problem) theres a space under that little table and I don't know why.

Here's the code for my table:

```
<div runat="server" class="ReportPage" >
  <table runat="server" class="ListReportBigTable" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td class="style13" colspan="3" >
         <table  width="46%" align="center"style="height:50%; "cellpadding="0"> 
           <tr>
             <td align="left"> 
               <asp:Label ID="LB_ChooseReport" runat="server" 
                  Text="Choisissez un dossier m&eacute;dical: " Font-Size="Small">
               </asp:Label>
             </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style="vertical-align:bottom" align="left">
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                 <ContentTemplate>
                   <div id="div_Filter" runat="server" visible="false" align="left">
                     <asp:Label ID="LBL_FilteredBy" runat="server" width="18%" Text="Patient : " 
                         Font-Size="Small" style="margin-left: 0px"></asp:Label>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_FilterSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                         Width="25%" CssClass="DDL_Filter" Font-Size="Small" Height="18px"></asp:DropDownList>
                   </div>
                 </ContentTemplate>
               </asp:UpdatePanel></td></tr></table>  
               <br />                 
             </td>
```

and here the CSS:

```
.ListReportBigTable
{
    height:25%;
    width:55%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border: thick solid black;  
     margin-left: 0px;
}
```

thx in advance

Comment: please give us the rendered HTML instead of your asp.net code, or even better: build us a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: in your `.ListReportBigTable` you could try `border-collapse: collapse` and/or `margin:0; padding:0`. That's all I can think of without the render

Comment: I'd like to post an image but i can't i don't have enough reputation to do it -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's a typo but you are closing with a `</td>` after your closing `</table>` tag. In addition you have a `<br />` before the closing misplaced `</td>` which would obviously add space to the bottom.

Try changing the closing `</td>` to `</table></div>` and removing the `<br />`

In addition, in your CSS try adding `margin-bottom: 0px;` and `padding-bottom: 0px;` to see if this has an effect.

Also, what is after the table? Maybe whatever is being displayed after the table has it's own top margin/padding?

Do you have a link to the actual page where this is occuring so we can examine with Firebug or similar and try to figure it out?

Comment: Made my day im such an idiot I Looked for hour to found my problem. Thx

Comment: Don't worry I've been in that position oh too many times before!